# How to ensure user-input data is an integer

Tags: c

I am new to C, but I know C#. In C#, I could use TryParse to ensure that the user typed in the correct datatype.

Here is the basic code I have for C:

```
int shallowDepth;

do
{
    printf ("\nEnter a depth for the shallow end between 2-5 feet: ");
    scanf ("%d", &shallowDepth);

    if (shallowDepth < 2 || shallowDepth > 5)
    {
        printf("\nThe depth of the shallow end must be between 2-5 feet.");
    }
}
while (shallowDepth < 2 || shallowDepth > 5);
```

The problem is if I type characters, such as "asdf", the program goes crazy and repeatedly says "Enter a depth for the shallow end between 2-5 feet: ". I'm not sure why this is exactly happening, but it has to be because it expects an int and I'm passing characters.

So how do I verify that the user inputted data is of int type before trying to store it in a variable? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because with `%d` `scanf` will refuse to touch anything that does not look like a number and leaves the text in the buffer. The next time around it will again reach the same text and so on.

I recommend that you ditch `scanf` for now and try something like `fgets` and then one of the functions in the `strtoXXX` family such as `strtoul` or `strtoumax`. These functions have a well-defined way of reporting errors and you can easily prompt the user for more text.

---

For example you could do:

```
char str[LENGTH];
long x;
if (!fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)) {
    /* Early EOF or error. Either way, bail. */
}

x = strtol(line, NULL, 10);
```

At this point you could use your number, but be aware that:

- You can specify a pointer for `strtol` to fill and it will point to the first unacceptable character
- If the result cannot be represented as a `long` then `strtol` will set `errno = ERANGE`. If you plan to test for this **you must set `errno = 0` before the `strtol`**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `scanf` you can't test it before. But you don't need too!

In your code if the user doesn't enter a number (or something that starts with a number), `scanf` returns 0, because it returns the number of parameters it could read.
So you need to check the return value of `scanf` to check if anything could be read.
Second, you need to remove everything that's still in the puffer.
You can use something like this for that:

```
while(getchar()!='\n');
```

If you want to handle files as well, you should catch `EOF` there, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
int shallowDepth;
int invalid;
do {
    int stat;
    invalid = 0;
    printf ("\nEnter a depth for the shallow end between 2-5 feet: ");
    stat = scanf ("%d", &shallowDepth);

    if(stat != 1){
        invalid = 1;
        while(getchar() != '\n');//clear stdin
    } else if (shallowDepth < 2 || shallowDepth > 5){
        invalid = 1;
        printf("\nThe depth of the shallow end must be between 2-5 feet.");
    }
}while (invalid);
```